# I want to integrate kendo-react with Microsoft bot framework

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I have taken kendo-react trail version I'm trying how it works when I use secret key of the bot which I have hosted on Azure. But it is not working.
I would be helpful if I get suggestion on how I can integrate bot.
I have installed all necessary packages.

Below is the complete code.

```
import { Chat } from '@progress/kendo-react-conversational-ui';
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';

 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = { messages: [] };
     this.client = new DirectLine({
      secret: "SECRET KEY"
      });
      this.client.activity$.subscribe(
            activity => this.onResponse(activity)
        );

       this.user = {
            id: 'User'
        };
        this.bot = {
            id: 'Botyo-BotTesting',
            name: 'Travel Agent',
            avatarUrl: 'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/chat/VacationBot.png'
        };

        this.addNewMessage = this.addNewMessage.bind(this);
   }

   parseText = ( event ) => {
    if (event.action !== undefined) {
        return event.action.value;
    } else if ( event.value ) {
        return event.value;
    } else {
        return event.message.text;
    }
}

   onResponse = (activity) => {
    let newMsg;
    if (activity.from.id === this.bot.id) {
        newMsg = {
            text: activity.text,
            author: this.bot,
            typing: activity.type === "typing",
            timestamp: new Date(activity.timestamp),
            suggestedActions: this.parseActions(activity.suggestedActions),
            attachments: activity.attachments ? activity.attachments : []
        };

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { messages: [...prevState.messages, newMsg] };
        });
    }
}


   addNewMessage = (event) => {
    let value = this.parseText(event);
    this.client.postActivity({
        from: { id: this.user.id, name: this.user.name },
        type: 'message',
        text: value
    }).subscribe(
        id => console.log("Posted activity, assigned ID ", id),
        error => console.log("Error posting activity", error)
    );
    if (!event.value) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { messages: [...prevState.messages, { author: this.user, text: value, timestamp: new Date() }] };
        });
    }
};


  render() {
    return (
      <Chat
      messages={this.state.messages}
      user={this.user}
      onMessageSend = {this.addNewMessage}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

A response from bot should be prompted first but even if i send Hi message it is not working.
Here is how the output looks like

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

The setup looks good, can you tell if the "onResponse" event is called? And if there is any activity in the event. This can give you in information if the issue is with the connection or with the Chat component and how the response is set.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The setup worked. I would like to render Adaptive cards. I tried, but after Submit action I'm unable to fetch the value and pass it on to bot framework. Could you please help me on this.